# Conditionally implement validation in form fields of an Angular 2 reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript

Can I conditionally implement validation in Angular 2 reactive form. I have this reactive form with 3 formControl fields one is a selection and the other two are input text for first name and last name. I want to conditionally implements validation for firstname and lastname based on the selection of the first field which is 'validateBy'. If the user selects 'byFirstName' only firstName should be validated. If the user selects 'byLastName'  only lastName should be validated. If the user selects 'byBoth' both firstName and lastName should be validated. I created a plunker for this. Only validation byBoth works.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.myForm = this._fb.group({
  validateBy: ['byFirstName'],
  firstName:  ['', isFirstNameValid(() => (this.validateBy === 'byFirstName' || this.validateBy === 'byBoth'),
                     Validators.required)],
  lastName: ['', isLastNameValid(() => (this.validateBy === 'byLastName' || this.validateBy === 'byBoth'),
                     Validators.required)],
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/X0zOGf?p=preview

Comment: you can if you write a custom directive validation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that your code evaluates the expression just once - when the `FormGroup` is created. You need to make it dynamic by creating your custom validator that will evaluate the expression every time it gets called:

```
this.personForm= this.fb.group({
  firstName: ['', Validators.required];
  lastName:  [
    '', 
    conditionalValidator(
      (() => this.isValidationForLastName === true),
      Validators.required
    )
  ]
});

function conditionalValidator(condition: (() => boolean), validator: ValidatorFn): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    if (! condition()) {
      return null;
    }
    return validator(control);
  }
}
```

Comment: Halasa I tried your code. now it doesn't validate :(

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Is the validator called? Do you have some error messages in the browser console?

Comment: just few changes what if my condition will be based on string not boolean. I updated my question.

Comment: With a string variable, you change just the condition function: `(() => this.isValidationForLastName === 'validateIt')`. If you implemented it and it doesn't work, please add your code to the question or create a plunker (or similar) example.

Comment: Halasa I updated my question and I already created a plunker similar to my problem. Can you check my plunker.

Comment: I edited your plunkr - you didn't set the validateBy attribute when the selection changed and I added AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity() calls to update validity info of the fields. See the working version: https://plnkr.co/edit/48MbhD?p=preview.

Comment: Wow Thank You so much @Halasa. That's exactly what I want to achieve :)

Comment: It will work but keep it in mind that validators are immutable and condition which it receives as an argument will be received only once and will not change after that.

Answer (score 11):

Another way of doing it would be something like this. Seems to work on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VA5d6G)

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      validateBy: ['byFirstName'],
      firstName:  [''],
      lastName: [''],
    });

    this.myForm.get('validateBy').valueChanges.subscribe(
        (validateBy : string) => {
          if (validateBy === 'byFirstName' || validateBy === 'byBoth') {
            this.myForm.get('firstName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
            this.myForm.get('firstName').updateValueAndValidity();
          }
          if (validateBy === 'byLastName' || validateBy == 'byBoth') {
            this.myForm.get('lastName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
            this.myForm.get('lastName').updateValueAndValidity();
          }

        };
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a [library](https://github.com/EliCDavis/ng-conditionally-validate) just for this.

Your solution might look something like:

```
constructor(private cv: ConditionallyValidateService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        validateBy: ['byFirstName'],
        firstName:  [''],
        lastName: [''],
     });

    cv.validate(this.myForm, 'firstName')
        .using(Validators.required)
        .when('validateBy')
        .is('byFirstName')

    cv.validate(this.myForm, 'lastName')
        .using(Validators.required)
        .when('validateBy')
        .is('byLastName')

    cv.validate(this.myForm, 'firstName', 'lastName')
        .using(Validators.required)
        .when('validateBy')
        .is('byBoth')

}
```