# toggle Validatos.required based upon condition, angular6

Tags: angular

I have a simple angular reactive form :

```
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['Benedict', [Validators.required]],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9.@]*')]],
    message: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(15)]]
  });
```

Is there any way I can do like this

`name: ['Benedict', [this.someCode == true ? Validators.required : '']]`

basically this validator toggle will be based upon some other fields value in actual form

Comment: Can you put the condition inside the validator? Make a custom validator which take a parameter

Comment: you should be using custom validator function here

Comment: you may check the official doc  there an example , hope it helps : https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Answer (score 0):

You need to create conditional custom validator function.please follow the below link

[Conditionally implement validation in form fields of an Angular 2 reactive form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490752/conditionally-implement-validation-in-form-fields-of-an-angular-2-reactive-form)